# How to convert Google Tink KeysetHandle to byte[ ] and back?

Tags: java, arrays, objectinputstream, tink

I'm trying to convert Google Tink's KeysetHandle into byte [] and to construct the KeysetHandle back from the byte [].

So here is the code I came up with

```
//Two functions for the conversion
public static String keyToString(KeysetHandle keysetHandle) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        CleartextKeysetHandle.write(keysetHandle, JsonKeysetWriter.withOutputStream(baos));
        oos.close();
        return Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static KeysetHandle stringToKey(String keysetString) {
    keysetString = keysetString.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","");
    try {
        List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] splitArray = keysetString.split(",");
        for (String x : splitArray) {
            list.add((byte) Integer.parseInt(x));
        }
        byte[] data = Bytes.toArray(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        KeysetHandle keysetHandle = CleartextKeysetHandle.read(JsonKeysetReader.withInputStream(ois));
        ois.close();
        return keysetHandle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Main Function :

```
KeysetHandle keyHandle = null;
try {
    AeadConfig.register();
    keyHandle = KeysetHandle.generateNew(KeyTemplates.get("AES128_GCM"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String keyString =keyToString(keyHandle);
System.out.println(keyString);
KeysetHandle fromString = stringToKey(keyString);
```

Output :

```
I/System.out: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 123, ...]
I/System.out: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 123, ...]
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null
        at com.google.crypto.tink.JsonKeysetReader.read(JsonKeysetReader.java:148)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.CleartextKeysetHandle.read(CleartextKeysetHandle.java:58)
        at com.ebenezer.testing.MainActivity.stringToKey(MainActivity.java:49)
        at com.ebenezer.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null
        at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:91)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.JsonKeysetReader.read(JsonKeysetReader.java:145)
        ... 18 more
```

I don't know why I am ending up with an error when I am trying to reconstruct a KeysetHandle object. Can someone please explain why this error is occuring or what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `baos`, to `JsonKeysetWriter.withOutputStream(baos)`. Try using the `ObjectOutputStream`, `oos`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, its working now, thank you so much :D